# How to detect file changes?

Tags: ruby

I am watching a log file using FSSM. So far, this works fine.

FSSM informs me whenever the file gets updated.
But how can I detect the new log entries without manipulating the given log file?

My current code is:

```
FSSM::Monitor.new.path(Dir.pwd, file) do
      update { |base, relative|
          puts "Change detected (#{file}): Base: #{base} Relative:#{relative}"
      }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking to basically tail the file, you'll want to keep an open handle to that file, and position it at the end.  Then, when new stuff is added, you just read from that handle and it should read you the "new stuff"

Comment: No need to keep the handle open. Just remember the `pos` of the file before closing it. A subsequent open could reposition to the same spot and continue reading to the end-of-file. That position information won't mysteriously change unless something does a total rewrite of the file.